# Passing data between two servers to be used in a script and then result returned to first server

Tags: php

I have come up against a problem whilst writing a script to check dates from a remote database. Due to pci compliance the client cannot allow access to all IP adresses which means that remote MySQL connection is not possible.

The solution i think is to have the main script located on the clients server and have the 'other' servers trigger this script.

For example: Server A has a script that runs and fills two variables $module and $domain.
This then needs to be passed to Server B, triggering script al_check.php which uses the results of $module and $domain to run it's code. Once al_check.php has completed it will contain a result in $valid of either 1 or 0. This needs to be passed back to Server A so that it can complete it's process.

I think i could use

```
include ('www.serverB.com/al_check.php');
```

But this would not be passing the two variables i need to the script before it is run on Server B.

Has anyone got suggestions on achieving this in a secure manner that is not going to require the Server B firewall to be opened to allow all?

Comment: Do you know CURL ? It may be a good solution to post variable to your remote script and retrieving content.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a script that respond in json on the remote server and call it with :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('www.serverB.com/al_check.php'));
```

$data will be an array with your values ;)

Comment: So $data would contain $module and $domain. But does this allow the result of al_check.php to be returned to Server A?

Comment: you make a call to the script, like you can do with your navigator, so just make the script to write {module: 'datamodule',domain: 'datadomain'} in it(in json) and $data will be a array which look like $data['module'] = datamodule and $data['domain'] = datadomain